# HTML code in Body

Tags: javascript, html, css, include

Hello everyone i need some help:
I have this:

```
A) Login.html
B) Documentation.html
C) Base.html
```

In the login i have a form with User and Password.
In Documentation, i have all the links to folders i include for exaple (Jquery,Bootraps, and more). 
In Base I have a part of code what i need for include in all pages. The code i have is:

```
<div id="loading">
    <div id="loading-msg" >
        <img src="img/spin.png" class="rotating">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is for do a logo rotating when a post it's waiting a answer from the server. With this (It's in Documentation.html):

```
    <script type="">
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#loading").fadeIn( 500 );
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
            $("#loading").fadeOut( 100 );
        });
</script>
```

Finally, my question it's: How i include the code in "Base.html" in "Login.html", because when i use: `<link href="../incluye/base.html" rel="import">` on Head, not works

Comment: It might be worth having a look into php. You can do this easy with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a typo in your html import - instead of `incluye` perhaps it should be `include`.

You can also use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function in jQuery to include the file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
  $("#target").load("Base.html"); 
});
</script>
```

Where `#target` is the id of the element into which you wish to load the content.

Comment: Nice!! Thanks so much

Comment: Oh sorry, i do it reciently. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the file extension to PHP and easily include the other files by using `<?PHP include 'yourfilename.php(extension)'`